# How to provide user security in MVC4 apicontroller using iPhone app

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc-4, restful-authentication

I develop new restful service using MVC4 web api for iphone application but I'm newbie for restful services thus I don't have any idea how to provide user security.

For example somebody who knows post url address, post anything to my tables. So how can I prevent this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution in this site

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/html-forms-and-multipart-mime

I hope this helps other newbie mvc4 wep api developers.

Comment: Unfortunately "The page you are looking for is not available".